# Simulate Enter press key without specifing the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried sendkeys plugin and others.

Is there a way to simulate Enter key pressed without element?

```
$("div.myclass").click(); // Put focus on my element - works
$("div.myclass span").sendkeys("Test"); // using sendkeys plugin send the input - works.

setTimeout(function(){
console.log('trigger');
//$("div._1mf").trigger({type: 'keydown', key: 'enter'}); // this one just insert new line...
e = jQuery.Event("keypress")
e.which = 13
    $("div.myclass").keypress(function(){ // this one doesn't work
    }).trigger(e)
},2000);
```

I have already element focused and input inserted, I need just simulate Enter press key to send the text, how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want to do is instead, submit the form that your input resides in?

Comment: The problem is that the form doesn't have submit button, it can be sent only by "Enter" key pressed

Comment: it doesn't need one, attach to the "onSubmit" of the form